# Electron/React application relative path to Json file not working in production

Tags: reactjs, debugging, electron

I am developing an Electron/react application whose main job is to read from a Json file and write back the changes to the Json file.

I have placed the json file inside the src folder. Everything is working in my development environment but the write back to json file is failing in the generated exe file.

The saving to json file part is handled in the electron.js file which is placed under the public folder.
I am accessing the json file like follow in the electron.js file-

const jsonFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/apis/data.json');

Then I am using this path inside my main renderer process.

My folder structure is as follows -

MyApp
 -Public
    -electron.js
    -index.html
-src
   -apis
     -data.json

Also I am unable to debug the electron side code in the production. The react part I can see in the dev tool but how to see it for the electon.js file?

Comment: Let me see your builder configuration. Which files and directories are you including while packaging?

Comment: For debug on production mode, you need to send the log or any related data to renderer via the IPC channel. use ipcMain and ipcRenderer.

Comment: Or this is a dirty method but you can execute on your terminal then logs will be displayed on your terminal

Comment: This is how the build configuration is done -                                                                           "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.electron-cra",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },

Comment: After build check your structure inside of asar file